# Getting all dates from previous 1 month, or 2 months in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to extract all the dates from the previous 1 or 2 months from the DB table (adempiere) field "dateinvoice"

For example if currently its 6 Jan 2012

I would like to extract all the data from 1 Dec 2011 - 31 Dec 2011 (previous 1 month), or 1 Nov 2011 - 31 Dec 2011 (previous 2 months)

I've seen some answers using DateAdd, I've recently learn that since I'm using PostgreSQL the DateAdd function doesn't work.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

**UPDATE**
I've followed Craigs recommendation and use SQLFiddle, my first time using it, so excuse me if i make any booboos

The link is here 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1d5d4/1
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1d5d4/3

I'm still getting errors even after changing the month to months...

**Update Number 2**
Im using Visual Studio to search all these queries. And Craigs recommendation does actually work. I've been getting the errors when im in the Query Designer, but when i Edit As Text. there seems to be no problem.

I'm not sure whether this error arises because of the Query Designer. But the query by Craig does work.. i think ill just stick to the text rather than the GUI Visual Studio offers for this problem . Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You likely want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE date_column BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' MONTH;
```

The `BETWEEN` operator is left-and-right inclusive. If you want right-exclusive you have to use separate `>=` and `<` tests instead.

Except for the `date_trunc` function that's ANSI-standard SQL, by the way, it's just that [Microsoft SQL Server doesn't implement the ANSI interval types or ANSI date maths](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432281/sql-server-doesnt-have-an-ansi-interval-data-type). Doing it a strictly ANSI-standard way would require you to replace the PostgreSQL-specific `date_trunc` with interval maths, [like this example of how to get the months I just cooked up in Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07fde/11). It's based on a subset of the sample data because of limitations in SQLFiddle for Oracle.

If you want to get the start of the current month, use `date_trunc`, eg:

```
SELECT date_trunc('2013-01-12');
```

will return `2013-01-01`. This can be combined with `INTERVAL` computations and the `extract` operation to do pretty much anything you need to with dates and times.

In this case, for the month before last I'd write:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE date_field BETWEEN date_trunc('month',current_date) - INTERVAL '2' MONTH 
                     AND (date_trunc('month',current_date) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH) - INTERVAL  '1' DAY;
```

(You want `INTERVAL '1' SECOND` instead of `INTERVAL '1' DAY` if you're working with timestamps not dates).

You'll notice the explicit parens for the interval subtraction. That's quite important, because dates are horrible nasty things. In date computations, `(a + b) + c` isn't necessarily the same as `a + (b + c)`. I was bitten by this recently, it's nasty.

Alternate phrasing, probably cleaner if you want `a <= x < b`:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE date_field >= date_trunc('month',current_date) - INTERVAL '2' MONTH
  AND date_field < date_trunc('month',current_date) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH;
```

Comment: OMG THANKS ALOT, i love the explanation, i havent tried it, gonna try it now, but the explanation really helps in my thinking and possibly also modify in the future. Thanks alot for taking the time!

Comment: When i Execute SQL. I got this error `Error in list of function arguments: '2' not recognized. Unable to parse query text`... Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: @user2500196 Which query? There are three there, and all three use bogus table names etc since you didn't give real ones. Please edit and update your question. Remove the SQL server tag, add your PostgreSQL version (which should be in EVERY question) and add the exact query text you tried as well as the exact error message. Or even better, put it in http://sqlfiddle.com/ .

Comment: Not too sure how to use sqlfiddle, ive edit and update my answer. Thanks for replying yet again

Comment: @user2500196 I got myself muddled, long day. I was correct with `MONTH` and it runs fine as expected with that amendment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1d5d4/7 . So I'm not sure how you got the error before.

Comment: Hey Craig, thanks for replying, it actually does work... But when im in the Query Designer for Visual Studio it has that error.. I'm just sticking to the text format rather than the GUI. Less problems here... Sorry for all the trouble. But really thanks alot!!!!!!!

Comment: @user2500196 Ah, would've been good to mention that detail. The Visual Studio query builder almost certainly only understands Microsoft SQL Server query syntax. So you'll want to use a regular text editor. BTW, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from adempiere where dateinvoice >  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '2 months'
```

Comment: Is GETDATE a SQL Server function? Because im getting errors using it

Comment: Try this. Sorry about the delay. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Like i said DateAdd doesnt work on PostGreSQL... Thanks for replying though

Comment: I modified my response. Does this work? Sorry I initially thought this was an MSSQL question. It's late :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It does work now, it does start from the CURRENT_DATE. Is it possible to start from the last day of the previous month? Say 30 June 2013?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDates](@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
WITH 
 N0 AS (SELECT 1 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N0 T1, N0 T2)
,N2 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N1 T1, N1 T2)
,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N2 T1, N2 T2)
,N4 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N3 T1, N3 T2)
,N5 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N4 T1, N4 T2)
,N6 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM N5 T1, N5 T2)
,NUMS AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NUM FROM N6)
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day,num-1,@StartDate) AS Date) as TheDate
FROM NUMS 
WHERE NUM <= DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@EndDate) + 1
);
```

**Execution SELECT * FROM dbo.GetDates('1 Dec 2011','31 Dec 2011');**

Comment: ALAS, that was my fault...I thought you were looking for MS SQL query.

Comment: Heh, it's not my question, I was just pointing it out. I'm puzzled as to why they've tagged it [tag:sql-server] when it's about [tag:postgresql].